# How can I pick almost random questions from a list depending on which level you are on?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm working on a project and I want to pick up different questions depending on which level you are on.

For example, the first 25 levels I want my system to pick easy questions for example in a 80% chance and medium questions in a 20%. At the end on level 80 I want the difficulty to slowly increase and the system will 100% only pick hard questions. How can I write a working slowly increasing graph matematically to implement to my arraypicker?

I have tried to shuffle `ArrayList` objects with:

```
Collections.shuffle(random);
```

for example in order to get percent, but I there should be an easier workaround this.

Hard to explain but I hope you understand, ask if you need more information.
I'm working on a libgdx project on Android studio

Comment: Can you add all questions in an arraylist sorted by difficulty, then get question as `myList.get(Math.random(level + whatever))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems wrapped up in one question, making your question a little broad for this site, but let's break down your issues:

- Create a question class with varying levels of difficulty. Let's call this class `Question` and level of difficulty, `Difficulty`
- Create a class that holds these questions in a collection or collections of some sort, and allow the user to request a random question from this class. Let's call this class `QuestionCollection` and the method used to request a random question, `public Question getRandomQuestion(...)`.
- Allow the user to have their own level of advancement. This can be the `User` class
- The distribution of the questions possibly received from the request `getRandomQuestion(...)` will depend on the User's level of advancement

So first to encapsulate level of difficulty, let's create an enum, one that has 3 (or more) levels:

```
public enum Difficulty {
    EASY, MEDIUM, HARD
}
```

Then the Question class can have a `private Difficulty difficulty;` field, one set in its constructor, and with a public getter method, `public Difficulty getDifficulty()`. A simplified Question class could look something like this:

```
public class Question {
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private Difficulty difficulty;

    public Question(String question, String answer, Difficulty difficulty) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public Difficulty getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

}
```

Again this is all an over simplification, but it can be used to help illustrate the problem and a possible solution.  If desired, you could have this class implement `Comparable<Question>`, and using Difficulty to help do the comparison, and allow you to sort a `List<Question>` by difficulty.

Then the key to all of this would be the `QuestionCollection` class, the one that held collection(s) of questions and that had the `getRandomQuestion(...)` method -- how to implement this.

One way, is to rather than worry about User level of advancement at this point, give the `getRandomQuestion(...)` method some parameters that allow the `QuestionCollection` to know what distribution to use. Easiest in my mind is to give it a relative frequency of difficulty, a percentage of `Difficulty.EASY`, `Difficulty.MEDIUM`, and `Difficulty.HARD`, something like:

```
public Question getRandomQuestion(int percentEasy, int percentMedium, int percentHard) {
    // ... code here to get the random question
}
```

OK, so now we're at how to build the internal workings of the `QuestionCollection` class, and then use this to get a proper distribution of random questions based on the parameter percentages. Probably the simplest is put a question into its own List, such as an ArrayList based on its level of Difficulty -- so here 3 Lists, one for EASY, one for MEDIUM and one for HARD questions.

So:

```
private List<Question> easyQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Question> mediumQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Question> hardQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or another possibly *cleaner* solution is to use a `Map<Difficulty, List<Question>>` rather than separate Lists, but I'll keep things simple for now and leave it at 3 Lists.

Then the class would have an `public void addQuestion(Question q)` method that would add questions to the correct list based on difficulty level:

```
public void addQuestion(Question q) {
    switch (q.getDifficulty()) {
    case EASY:
        easyQuestions.add(q);
        break;
    case MEDIUM:
        mediumQuestions.add(q);
        break;
    case HARD:
        hardQuestions.add(q);
    }
}
```

OK, so we've got our lists filled with questions, we're now at the core issue of how to get the right distribution of randomization?  I would recommend a 2 step process -- first use `Math.random()` or an instance of the Random class to choose *which list* to get a question from, and then use use randomization to select a random question from within the chosen list.

So the first step, getting the random List could look like so:

```
// declare variable before the if blocks
List<Question> randomList = null;

// get a random int from 0 to 99
int rand = (int) (100 * Math.random());

// get the random list using basic math and if blocks
if (rand < percentEasy) {
    randomList = easyQuestions;
} else if (rand < percentEasy + percentMedium) {
    randomList = mediumQuestions;
} else {
    randomList = hardQuestions;
}
```

OK once the randomList has been obtained, then get a random question from it:

```
// first get a random index to the list from 0 to < size
int size = randomList.size();
int listIndex = (int)(size * Math.random());
Question randomQuestion = randomList.get(listIndex);
return randomQuestion;
```

The whole `QuestionCollection` class (simplified version) could look like so:

```
// imports here

public class QuestionCollection {
    private List<Question> easyQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Question> mediumQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Question> hardQuestions = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addQuestion(Question q) {
        switch (q.getDifficulty()) {
        case EASY:
            easyQuestions.add(q);
            break;
        case MEDIUM:
            mediumQuestions.add(q);
            break;
        case HARD:
            hardQuestions.add(q);
        }
    }

    public Question getRandomQuestion(int percentEasy, int percentMedium, int percentHard) {
        // if the numbers don't add up to 100, the distribution is broken -- throw an exception
        if (percentEasy + percentMedium + percentHard != 100) {
            String format = "For percentEasy: %d, percentMedium: %d, percentHard: %d";
            String text = String.format(format, percentEasy, percentMedium, percentHard);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
        }

        List<Question> randomList = null;
        int rand = (int) (100 * Math.random());
        if (rand < percentEasy) {
            randomList = easyQuestions;
        } else if (rand < percentEasy + percentMedium) {
            randomList = mediumQuestions;
        } else {
            randomList = hardQuestions;
        }

        // we've now selected the correct List
        // now get a random question from the list:

        // first get a random index to the list from 0 to < size
        int size = randomList.size();
        int listIndex = (int)(size * Math.random());
        Question randomQuestion = randomList.get(listIndex);
        return randomQuestion;
    }
}
```

---

So to test proof of concept, a test program shows that the distribution works:

```
// imports

public class QuestionFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create QuestionCollection object
        QuestionCollection questionCollection = new QuestionCollection();

        // fill it with questions with random difficulty
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            String question = "Question #" + i;
            String answer = "Answer #" + i;
            int randomIndex = (int) (Difficulty.values().length * Math.random());
            Difficulty difficulty = Difficulty.values()[randomIndex];
            Question q = new Question(question, answer, difficulty);
            questionCollection.addQuestion(q);
        }

        Map<Difficulty, Integer> frequencyDistMap = new EnumMap<>(Difficulty.class);
        for (Difficulty diff : Difficulty.values()) {
            frequencyDistMap.put(diff, 0);
        }

        int easyPercent = 20;
        int mediumPercent = 70;
        int hardPercent = 10;

        int questionCount = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < questionCount; i++) {
            Question q = questionCollection.getRandomQuestion(easyPercent, mediumPercent, hardPercent);
            Difficulty difficulty = q.getDifficulty();
            int currentCount = frequencyDistMap.get(difficulty);
            currentCount++;
            frequencyDistMap.put(difficulty, currentCount);
        }

        System.out.println("Difficulty: Count (Percent)");
        String format = "%-12s %4d   (%02d)%n";
        for (Difficulty difficulty : Difficulty.values()) {
            int number = frequencyDistMap.get(difficulty);
            int percent = (int) Math.round((100.0 * number) / questionCount);
            System.out.printf(format, difficulty + ":", number, percent);
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns the original distribution percentages:

```
Difficulty: Count (Percent)
EASY:      200325   (20)
MEDIUM:    699341   (70)
HARD:      100334   (10)
```